# How can I get Vitest to mock an RTK Query Hook

Tags: reactjs, vite, react-testing-library, rtk-query

I am trying to use Vitest for the first time and am having real issues with it working for mocking my RTK Query hooks.

I have tried to create a [mock for the data structure](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/queries#frequently-used-query-hook-return-values) outline in the RTK docs.

Here is my test code:

```
import { vi } from "vitest"
import { ReactElement } from "react"
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react"
import { FormProvider, useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import SelectField from "./SelectField"

// Mock the useGetFieldValueQuery hook
vi.mock("path/to/rtkQueryCreateApi", () => {
  console.log("Mock called")

  return {
    useGetFieldValueQuery: vi.fn(() => ({
      data: {
        d: {
          results: [
            { id: "1", text: "Option 1" },
            { id: "2", text: "Option 2" },
          ],
        },
      },
      isLoading: false,
      isError: false,
      isSuccess: true,
      error: null,
      refetch: vi.fn(),
    })),
  }
})

const mockElement = {
  label: "Test Select Label",
  fieldName: "testField",
  componentType: "checkbox",
  id: "test-checkbox",
  width: 3,
}

type WrapperProps = {
  children: ReactElement
}

describe("SelectField Component", () => {
  it("renders options correctly from string filter", () => {
    const Wrapper = ({ children }: WrapperProps) => {
      const methods = useForm()
      return <FormProvider {...methods}>{children}</FormProvider>
    }

    render(
      <Wrapper>
        <SelectField element={mockElement} errors={undefined} />
      </Wrapper>,
    )

    // Check if the options are rendered
    expect(screen.getByText("Option 1")).toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(screen.getByText("Option 2")).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

Here is the output I get in the console when I run `npm run test`.

`TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'data' of 'useGetFieldValueQuery(...)' as it is undefined.`

I am using:

- `"vitest": "^0.30.1"`
- `"react": "^18.2.0"`

Any idea would be great as I can't seem to get anything to avoid the undefined error.

I have double checked the path to the mocked hook and it is correct. I can also confirm that I can see the `Mock called` log in the console. I appreciate I could probably use MSW at a lower level to avoid this but if possible I would like to get the mock to work.